# jpa hibernate nvarchar to varchar conversion on sql server

Tags: sql-server, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I am running a jpa query, i defined all the values as varchar but when i am checking the running query in sql server it is showing as nvarchar, can any one explain this.

JPA QUERY : List findByBatchNameAndFilenameAndIngestionStatusAndVendorName(String batchName, String filename, int status, String vendorName);

Sql Server Query: RPC:Starting    exec sp_executesql N'select ingestdocs0_.ID as ID1_0_, ingestdocs0_.BATCH_NAME as BATCH_NA2_0_, ingestdocs0_.BRAND as BRAND3_0_, ingestdocs0_.COMMENTS as COMMENTS4_0_, ingestdocs0_.Doc_Type_Code as Doc_Type5_0_, ingestdocs0_.CONTENT_FILE_NAME as CONTENT_6_0_, ingestdocs0_.P8_GUID as P7_0_, ingestdocs0_.INGESTION_STATUS as INGESTIO8_0_, ingestdocs0_.LOAN_NUMBER as LOAN_NUM9_0_, ingestdocs0_.PROCESS_DATE as PROCESS10_0_, ingestdocs0_.Status_Code as Status_11_0_, ingestdocs0_.Vendor_Name as Vendor_12_0_ from dbo.BKFS_Invoice_Ingestion ingestdocs0_ where ingestdocs0_.BATCH_NAME=@P0 and ingestdocs0_.CONTENT_FILE_NAME=@P1 and ingestdocs0_.INGESTION_STATUS=@P2 and ingestdocs0_.Vendor_Name=@P3                                ',N'@P0 nvarchar(4000),@P1 nvarchar(4000),@P2 int,@P3 nvarchar(4000)

Answer (score 0):

It seems this is what the JDBC driver/database infers for the parameter types. AFAICS this has nothing to do with Hibernate or Spring. What you are showing here is what the JDBC driver is doing when preparing/executing a statement.